# Things to check before publishing?

Tags: publishing

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask but do you have a checklist of typegraphic things to check before publishing the book or document? Rather than typos and grammar issues, I'm thinking of things like page format, margins, tables and figures alignment, orphans and widows, etc.

Is there any LaTeX package or similar that can help with things like that?

Comment: sorry design is off topic here, although of course implementing your chosen design in tex would be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of different style guides, depending on the type of document and publicistic agency.

One of the resources that provides list of most of them are the following:

- https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_style_guides
- https://subjectguides.library.american.edu/citation

  Pay attention to the sidebar with different tabs that makes the styles sectioned and ordered relatively.

  [image]

---

Speaking of LaTeX side, the most popular package for managing your document's layout is [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) that allows to customize the paper any way you wish.

[image]